# access 2016: toggle between open forms by using Alt+Tab

Tags: forms, user-interface, ms-access

Access 2016 database, Roughly 10 forms of which I need 2 or 3 open at same time. (By the way: the forms are linked to seperate tables)

I know I can open multiple forms but I need to be able to toggle between the open forms using "Alt+Tab" ..... anyone know if this is possible?

Thank you in advance... Tjay

Comment: Does shift-tab work?

Comment: No, Shift-tab only moves to previous field in tab order (opposite of Tab).

Comment: According to this link, the shortcut you want is `CTRL-F6`. I'm not aware of a way to override the windows ALT-TAB. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-access-70a673e4-4f7b-4300-b8e5-3320fa6606e2#bkmk_navworkspace

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that only works at design time.... I'm needing to use Alt+tab at runtime.  Currently I'm having to switch forms by grabbing the mouse and clicking.... ggrrrrr. frustrating.

Comment: Seems to work for me at runtime - that is I have two open forms that are 'open'. They are shown in tabs and CTRL-F6 switches between the two tabs. I'm using Office 365 (local install)version 1804

Comment: I guess that's why it's not working, my forms are not tabbed forms.... they're two distinct forms.... like two different apps/programs.  In other words, I can have one form on my left monitor and the other form on my main monitor......hmm, what to try, what to try.... thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Normally in MS Access the forms are inside the main application window. Does your application window span two screens?

Comment: My forms are not in the main application window.  The forms open up independently and then I put them on seperate screens.

Comment: OK. On my forms I set the _Pop Up_ property to _Yes_ - I guess that is what you are doing? And you're right CTRL-F6 doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, I've got the Pop Up set to Yes.  Sure seems like there would be a property setting or something I could set.

Comment: Why not using the events key_press / key_down / key_up to  programmaticlly set focus to the other form?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that but it might work.  I really like the Alt+Tab functionality b/c you can see what you want to tab to and just keep tabbing until you get there.... not sure my skill level is good enough to make pics popup and tab through.... but it's not a bad idea at all.... thank you.