# Access 2016: Alt+Tab...toggle between open forms by using Alt+Tab

Tags: forms, ms-access

I've got roughly 10 forms of which I need 2 or 3 open at same time. (BTW: the forms are linked to separate tables)  I know I can open multiple forms but I need to be able to toggle between the open forms using "Alt+Tab" ..... anyone know if this is possible?  Thank you in advance... Tjay

BTW: I posted on Stackoverflow as well and got some great tips but didn't accomplish what I was needing.

Comment: *I posted on Stackoverflow as well* -- you *are* on Stack Overflow. Where is the other post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access 2016: toggle between open forms by using Alt+Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114069/access-2016-toggle-between-open-forms-by-using-alttab)

Comment: @Andre He reposted it from yesterday.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed too. :) @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your other post ([Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114069/access-2016-toggle-between-open-forms-by-using-alttab)):

This cannot be done with use of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you would need to use the MS Access shortcut setup in the design of the program <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

It is not possible to override the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Windows function programmatically to achieve the results you are looking for.

Here's a simple question for you though; why would you "need to be able to toggle between the open forms using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>"? Is there some specific reason you need <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to accomplish your goal? Perhaps what you need can be accomplished through some other means.

For instance, you can setup events such as SetFocus for specific forms after certain events have been finalized, while not an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to a form, it accomplishes a similiar end result.

Comment: The reason I need separate forms is so I can reference my purchase orders on my left screen and inventory on right screen... but I guess looking like I'm out of luck ... thank you.